# Получение адреса из geoObject в YandexMapKit

Tags: ios, yandexmapkit

Версия YandexMapKit 3.5.0. Нужно по нажатию на объект на карте вывести адрес этого объекта. Я подписываюсь на нажатия на объекты на карте:

```
let map = mapView.mapWindow.map
map.addTapListener(with: self)
```

Дальше создаю обработчик нажатия:

```
extension MyClass: YMKLayersGeoObjectTapListener {
    func onObjectTap(with event: YMKGeoObjectTapEvent) -> Bool {
        print("Tapped")
        return true
    }
}
```

А как получить адрес?
Как я понял из документации, необходимые мне данные хранятся в metadataContainer, но как их получить - я не нашел. Пробовал такую конструкцию, но она ничего не даёт.

```
let objMetadata = event.geoObject.metadataContainer.getItemOf(YMKGeoObject.self) as? YMKGeoObject
```

Есть какие-то идеи на этот счет?

Comment: Вот посмотрите я уже отвечал на подобный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079461/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba/1079895#1079895

Comment: @ schmidt9, спасибо за ваш ответ. Я видел этот пост, вы там используете YMKSearchToponymObjectMetadata в качестве представления данных. У меня этот метод также не работает, у полученного таким образом объекта нет свойства address. Думаю это из-за того, что вы получаете ответ из поискового запроса YMKSearchResponse, а у меня немного другая задача, я хочу нажатия на карту обрабатывать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать такой вариант - получить координаты объекта и по ним уже определить подробные данные, используя метод, который я уже приводил [в другом своем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079461/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA/1079895#1079895)

```
class LocationAtTapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: YMKMapView!

    let searchManager = YMKSearch.sharedInstance().createSearchManager(with: .combined)
    var searchSession: YMKSearchSession?

    let TARGET_LOCATION = YMKPoint(latitude: 59.945933, longitude: 30.320045)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.mapWindow.map.move(
            with: YMKCameraPosition(target: TARGET_LOCATION, zoom: 15, azimuth: 0, tilt: 0),
            animationType: YMKAnimation(type: YMKAnimationType.smooth, duration: 0.2),
            cameraCallback: nil)

        mapView.mapWindow.map.addTapListener(with: self)
    }

}

extension LocationAtTapViewController: YMKLayersGeoObjectTapListener {
    func onObjectTap(with event: YMKGeoObjectTapEvent) -> Bool {
        let obj = event.geoObject
        print("name:", obj.name ?? "unknown")

        guard let point = obj.geometry.first?.point else {
            return true
        }

        print("coordinates: lat \(point.latitude) lon \(point.longitude)")

        let responseHandler = {(searchResponse: YMKSearchResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let response = searchResponse {
                self.onSearchResponse(response)
            }
        }

        searchSession = searchManager.submit(with: point, zoom: 15, searchOptions: YMKSearchOptions(), responseHandler: responseHandler)

        return true
    }

    func onSearchResponse(_ response: YMKSearchResponse) {

        for searchResult in response.collection.children {
            guard let obj = searchResult.obj else {
                continue
            }

            guard let objMetadata = obj.metadataContainer.getItemOf(YMKSearchToponymObjectMetadata.self) as? YMKSearchToponymObjectMetadata else {
                continue
            }

            let address = objMetadata.address

            let formattedAddress = address.formattedAddress
            let postalCode = address.postalCode ?? "none"
            let additionalInfo = address.additionalInfo ?? "none"

            print("formattedAddress", formattedAddress)
            print("postalCode", postalCode)
            print("additionalInfo", additionalInfo)

            print("components:")

            address.components.forEach {
                let value = $0.name

                $0.kinds.forEach {
                    let kind = YMKSearchComponentKind(rawValue: UInt(truncating: $0))

                    switch kind {

                    case .country:
                        print("country: \(value)")

                    case .region:
                        print("region: \(value)")

                    case .locality:
                        print("locality: \(value)")

                    case .street:
                        print("street: \(value)")

                    case .house:
                        print("house number: \(value)")

                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            }

            print("==========")
        }
    }
}
```